# This cannot be true. Can it?

Tags: humor

Grandpa smiled and said:

> "You know my cousin, lives in Florida, turned 85 yesterday. He told me that he walks thirty miles every day!"

"What? No way. That's more than 20 hours of walking!" I said

"True my son. But he is telling the truth. And no, he is not dreaming or that sort of thing" said Grandpa.

How can this be? How can a statement like that be true and false at the same time?

Note:

> many of you might have read this as a joke somewhere. So did I. I just turned it into a humorous puzzle. Please let folks who have not seen this before solve it. Thanks

Comment: If the [tag:geography] tag were included I'd say Grandpa's cousin gnxrf n jnyx qbja 30n rirel qnl, but alas, probably not the answer 

Comment: Right @Taco. Only the Humor tag. You will see why.

Comment: I'm counting on it lol

Comment: It strikes me that rot13(Guvegl Zvyrf vf n irel fgenatr anzr sbe n qbt...!)

Comment: oops, i read @stiv's comment after my guess.  Sorry

Comment: @SteveV Great minds... :)

Comment: From the description of [[tag:humor]]: "Please do not use this tag to post simple jokes which are not puzzles, and remember that questions should be uniquely answerable." -  I don't know if this is applicable here, and I hope it isn't. Just noting.

Comment: 20-25 minutes a mile is a pretty normal walking speed. For an 85 year old healthy enough to walk that far, that number might be closer to 30-40 minutes. So we're looking at a range of 10-20 hours.

Comment: Is he walking on the bus?

Comment: Perhaps something along the lines that grandpa walks rot13([Sybevqn Fgngr Ebhgr] 30 [sbe n pbhcyr bs] zvyrf rirel qnl [gb trg gb gur fubcf/ornpu/pnsr/jungrire])

Comment: What is that language?

Comment: LoL since ["Florida man"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florida_Man) is a thing, a quick search led me to [this relevant article](https://www.firstcoastnews.com/amp/article/news/florida-man-walks-30-miles-a-day-for-childhood-obesity-awareness/77-262624337)

Comment: Just noting... why is Grandpa replying to his grandchild as "True my **son**"?

Comment: Closed... so what was the answer? I hope we get to find out.

Comment: @Amoz Gur bevtvany wbxr ba n fbpvny zrqvn fvgr jnf: "V anzrq zl qbt 5zvyrf fb V pna gryy crbcyr V jnyx svir zvyrf rirel qnl. Gur (fvpx) sbyybj hc ol fbzrbar jnf "V ena bire 5 zvyrf gbqnl"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps

> his dog is named "thirty miles"?  In which case I'm sure TM appreciates it

Comment: Doesn't fit with the reply "True".

Comment: Or, to vary it, perhaps he walks thirty dogs, all named Miles.

Comment: Maybe his other dog, "20 hours of walking", only gets walked every other day?

Comment: How does that make the statement be "true and false at the same time"?

Comment: @Wyck (rot13)(Gehr: ur jnyxrq guvegl zvyrf rirel qnl (jurer guvegl zvyrf vf uvf qbt)
Snyfr: ur jnyxrq guvegl zvyrf rirel qnl (jurer guvegl zvyrf vf n qvfgnapr))

Comment: @msh210: It does fit, because grandpa is simply acknowledging that it would take over 20 hours to walk that far, but he is not saying that his cousin actually spends that amount of time walking.

Comment: I believe these cases would be disambiguated by capitalization., diminishing the written form of this puzzle.  It would work if spoken though.

Comment: He confirms the "over 20 miles of walking", but that doesn't have to be in a day. Grandpa could be agreeing that walking TM every day adds up to over 20 miles over the year or something.

Answer (score 11):

> - So he told you he once walked 30 miles?
>   - Yeah, and he told me that every day.

Comment: Doesn't really fit with the tenses used in the problem statement.

Comment: This seems to be the best fit so far.

Comment: Agree the question should be better worded, the tenses don't make much sense here. Every day, the 85-year-old cousin told Grandpa that he walks 30 miles. That's not true unless the cousin actually "walks 30 miles", and the tense here indicates that he does so in a repeated, ongoing sense. "I walk 30 miles" means that you have done it before, and intend to do it again. Similarly "I go to the gym on Thursdays" is false if you have no intention of going to the gym in the future, regardless of what you've done in the past.

Comment: I agree, the tenses are a problem.  But I like the answer anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps Grandpa is walking

> thirty dogs named Miles simultaneously for about 40 minutes.

Doing the math, that would total about 20 hours of walking overall.

Comment: I'd argue the dogs must be named "Mile", or it would say he walked 30 Mileses. Clever answer!

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, he means that

> He walked 30 miles every *calendar* day, over the course of his 85 years - so, 20 hours of walking in total on those 85 Jan. 1s, 85 Jan. 2s, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It’s possible

> they’re not talking about Earth days. 1 day on Mercury is about 58 Earth days and 1 day on Venus is 116 Earth days. Plenty of time to walk 30 miles. These guys might be astronomy buffs or something.

Answer (score 1):

He does not walk 30 miles a day, obviously. However, the Earth rotates on its axis. So even though you are standing in the same place, you will still be moving through space.

That means, he walks slowly, the Earth moves. When he has moved 30 miles through space, he stops walking. So thats why the statement is true and false at the same time, because he did walk, moved a distance of 30 miles (through space), even though he did not walk that far ON EARTH.

Answer (score 0):

Probably

> He means the speed of the Earth. Earth rotates around its axis with
>  the speed of 1,000 miles per hour, while moving around the Sun with
>  the approximate speed of 67,000 miles per hour. Yes, he says that he
>  walks only 30  miles, but probably he just acknowledges the achieving
>  of his own goal of 30 miles every day.